# Program to help when presenting java code?

Tags: java, windows

I was at a conference and there were one presenter who showed some Java 8 code examples in an application, and I'm looking for the name of that or a similar app.

The application compiled all code examples and showed output but the main thing was that he didnt have to write complete java code. It automatically handled imports and class definitions. He could just focus on code he wanted to show. This made it easy to quickly create examples.

Edit; A clarification, this was not a complete IDE. It appeared to be a program specifically designed for quickly writing and testing short code examples. For example, he wrote and showed a for-each loop in Java 8, without any imports or having to create a main class or any of that syntactic fluff.

Comment: One of my main gripes is IDEs that recognise syntax and the library it came from but don't give you the option to automatically include it - grrr!

Comment: The only thing I can remember that does something similar to what you're saying (although I doubt it was what was being used) is beanshell (http://www.beanshell.org).

Comment: After a quick search I found closure java shell http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.java.shell/sh which sounds something more likely to be currently used instead of old deprecated beanshell

Comment: Sounds more like a sandbox. There are plenty out there - or he could have rolled his own...

Answer (score 4):

Check those Integrated Development Environments:

- [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)
- [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
- [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/)

To improve your presentation you can create templates which will create necessary code for you.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. This application wasn't a full IDE. It appeared to be specifically designed for quick and short code examples. Edited to my q to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the contact details of the presenter and asked about the program. It turns out he was using Mac with TextMate.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse provides a similiar feature with its [java scrapbook pages](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm).

You can just enter java statements and they can be run.